# Translate User input to French

Tags: translation

I would like to know if there is a way/ method that can translate user entered description to the default language of user ?

Ex: User enters customer description in English. But portal user changed his/ her language to French. Is there a way to translate the description automatically to French.

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm afraid there is not such out-of-the box feature in Salesforce. A possible solution would be to call an external service, like Google Translate. You can, for example, implement a trigger: each time the user enters or updates the description field, the trigger detect the language of the current user and calls an external web service that will do the translation. Then the trigger stores the translated description in a new custom field (or the same field it doesn't matter).

However, it is just theoretical solution, I have neved tested such thing. Good luck.

Comment: I had the same thing in mind but interested in knowing if anyone was successful in implementing this. I will try giving this idea a try.

Comment: However, it seems that Google Translate is paid, it doesn't offer a free service.

Comment: Ya.  I just checked. Are there any ideas ?

Comment: Check out Microsoft Translator API, it's free for small volumes.

Answer (score -2):

At S4G we have built an App that provides a solution for what you are looking for. Now, you can translate all your Salesforce fields from any language, any object and for any operation with Google Translate. We invite you to check it now in Salesforce AppExchange. Link: (https://sforce.co/2OtOr2L)

You will find the faq and more information on our website (http://s4g.es/omnitranslate). If you have any other questions please contact us through the following email omnitranslate@s4g.es.

Hope you find it interesting! Regards.